# iOS 8 How to use document provider extension with navigation controller?

Tags: ios, ios8

How i can put document provider extension in navigation controller to use the push and pop methods? iCloud document provider use it so I think it is possible, but when i embed document provider controller in navigation controller I receive an exception. When I pick my document provider i receive alert message on the screen "Failed to launch 'docProvider'", "The document picker 'docProvider' failed to launch(4097)."

```
    17545849:_UIScreenEdgePanRecognizerEdgeSettings.edgeRegionSize=13.000000
2014-08-25 10:43:16.948 documentProvider[1851:423858] <NSXPCConnection: 0x15526e50> connection from pid 1849: Warning: Exception caught during decoding of received message, dropping incoming message.
Exception: Exception while decoding argument 0 (#2 of invocation):
<NSInvocation: 0x1554f0d0>
return value: {v} void
target: {@} 0x0
selector: {:} __connectToViewControllerFromRemoteViewController:replyHandler:
argument 2: {@} 0x0
argument 3: {@?} 0x0 (block)

Exception: value for key '<no key>' was of unexpected class '_NSXPCDistantObject'. Allowed classes are '{(
    NSNumber,
    NSNull,
    NSString,
    NSData,
    NSDate,
    NSDictionary,
    NSArray
)}'.
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code you are trying?

Comment: I have just embed the view controller in navigation controller in the IB and connected button with push segue with other control. But the extension is crashing before showing the first controller.

Comment: Very difficult to help without more information. At the very least, please post a symbolicated exception log.

Comment: When I pick my document provider i receive alert message on the screen "Failed to launch 'docProvider'", "The document picker 'docProvider' failed to launch(4097)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the properties IBOutlet that you need on the .h

```
   @interface DocumentPickerViewController : UIDocumentPickerExtensionViewController {

         IBOutlet UILabel *description;
   }

   @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *description;
```

And at the .m:

```
   @implementation DocumentPickerViewController

   @synthesize description;
```

Finally you have to link the IBOutlet on your StoryBoard

---

Also yo can have the same error if you are using the Extension with 32Bits architecture.

To solve it you have to change on the Project in the Target of your Document Provider on the Build Settings at section Architectures the $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) to $(ARCHS_STANDARD) <- this is 64bits